# JDBC/MySQL how do you deal with ints longer out of the range of integer?

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

So I'm writing code in JDBC to get a resultset in a loop. The problem is, in the database the field is INT(9). When I import it, if I set an int to that value from a resultset, it truncates it to a different 3-digit int. If, however, I set the variable reading the data in as a long, it's correct. So I can get the right data, that's all well-and-good.

Now, when trying to get a different resultset using that previously found number, my resultset ends up empty. I tried:

```
    long SSN = 100200300;

    pStatement = connect.prepareStatement("SELECT Name FROM Person p WHERE p.ID=?");

        ResultSet rs;
```

Later in a loop:

```
    pStatement.setLong(1, SSN);
    rs = pStatement.executeQuery();
```

And it always ends up empty. I also cannot use pStatement.setInt, because it's a long. Any ideas on how to deal with INT type of large numbers in a db when working in JDBC?

Comment: long = 64bit, mysql int = 32bit. if you want to have a 1:1 mapping, then you should use a mysql bigint, which is 64bit as well.

Comment: "... it truncates it to a different 3-digit int." - What does that mean?

Comment: That worked. I figured it out from there. Thanks. I meant it was converting the number, for instance, 100200300 to 101 or something.